# Is there a way to pin a version of sudo apt upgrade for the whole Os/all packages?

Tags: ubuntu, apt

Hi I'm writing some bash scripts to install some VMs

I run...

`sudo apt update -y`

`sudo apt upgrade -y`

Those work fine...

But is there a way to make sure that if I run those 2 commands somewhere in the future to install new VMs that we get the exact same versions on the newer machines?

I just want to make sure that my script is repeatable.

Comment: Why would you want that? If you require static software update a VM to a known state, and generalize that image?

Comment: I'm writing script to install XYZ platform on dev. Now say I'm ready to go live on prod 2 weeks from now. How do i make sure that the prod has the exact same versions.

So we cannot have the dev env on old versions and production platform on newer versions. we make sure we deploy same versions and then at som point we test the dev platform for patches and then apply patches to prod.

Comment: Create images and don't run upgrades on them?

Comment: Ah yeah I guess I can create base image with the current "upgrade" and then run scripts that install specific version of packages.